# finding the pdf of a random variable from the pdf of a different one

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose a company produced a maximum of 1 ton of a product per day (call it rv Y) that has the pdf(X) = 2x over (0,1) and 0 elsewhere.  The company can sell this product for 500 dollars per ton but has fixed costs daily of 200 dollars.  Find the pdf Z of the random variable representing the company's daily profit.

---

my attempt:

I reasoned that W=300y-200 from the problem description.  Fy(y) (the cdf of Y) is y^2 on (0,1) and 0 elsewhere.

Thus we have:

Fw(w) = P(W<=w) by definition of cdf of w

=P(300y-200<=w)

=P(y<=(w+200)/300)

=Fy((w+200)/300)

Taking the derivative w.r.t. w on both sides, by the fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule the pdf of W fw(w) is:

fw(w)=2*(w+200)/300) * d/dw[(w+200/300)]

= 2*(w+200)/300)*1/300

So fw(w) = 2*(w+200)/300)*1/300 on (-200,300) and 0 elsewhere but the integral over this interval doesn't equal 1.

Comment: You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) section helpful for the general approach.

Comment: Thanks.  So working through that, I got the pdf of z is f(z) = (400z+800)/500^2 in (-200, 300) and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to show your work.

Comment: Do they sell it for 500/ton or 300/ton? Also how did you get the square term in the last step?  The derivative of CDF $F_Y(y)$ is PDF $f_Y(y)$

Comment: oops, updated. its 500 per.

Comment: check your support

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by support?

Comment: (-200,300)...double check that

Comment: ugh cant believe i missed that. thanks!